# how to create auto run file using python on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I need to run file automatically while logging into the system in python on ubuntu.Can anyone guide me to how to create auto run file using python on ubuntu.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your file as executable (`chmod +x file.py`) and in `Startup Applications` (find it in the dash) you can add a new startup program and add your file by browsing for it `path_to_file>/<file>.py` and that'll make it executable at login.

You can also [create a cron job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: My answer has the same effect as the accepted answer: it still creates the `~/.config/autostart/file.desktop` file. I understand you'd like more control by creating it and maybe adding more options, but it doesn't mean my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

first go to home and press ctrl+h now u can see hidden folders and click .config folder if autostart folder is available means just create file with desktop extension eg : auto.dsesktop .

type the following command in terminal

```
gedit .config/autostart/auto.desktop
```

and enter the following commands in auto.destop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python filename.py #this is execution part so u can modify whatever u needs
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=<Name_to_be_displayed>
Comment=<optional comment>
```